# How to push value of input on jQuery's keyup into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

basically I have a bunch of nested forms using Rails Cocoon library and there are multiple `.stage-time.stop_time` inputs (depending on the number of forms).

Basically, my plan was to..

- On `.stage-time.stop_time` keyup, get the value of `this` input
- Depending on which form you are on... push it to the array
- Push it it to an array
- And eventually do something with the array...

`var stopTimeArray = []`

`$('.mdl-textfield__input.stage-time.stop_time').keyup('input', function() {`

```
  var stopTimeVal = parseInt(this.value)
  // index gets the rel of the current form. This works perfectly!
  var index = parse($(getCurrentStage()).attr('rel')) - 1 
  // if you are on the first form, push the stopTimeVal in the 0th index of array
  stopTimeArray[index] = stopTimeVal
  updateTTH()
}

function updateTTH() {
  console.log(stopTimeArray)
  // other code...
}
```

But the problem happens when I enter something in the second form. It assigns `undefined` to all the previous elements.

Suppose I enter *20* in the **first** form, `updateTTH()` will print

> => [20]
>
> => [20]
> *(twice because it is triggering keyup twice)*

But... in the **second** form... suppose I enter *30*... `updateTTH()` will print

> => [undefined × 1, 30]
>
> => [undefined × 1, 30]

I guess this is happening because stopTimeArray[index - 1] doesn't exist anymore on the `.keyup()` method... but, I tried many things to go around this, but I am out of ideas.

[HERE is a YouTube video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xl1sKLDrA_A)

Comment: Each time a keyup happens, the first thing you do is assign an empty array to stopTimeArray.

Comment: @James, I orignally had it outside of the function, but it was still giving the same results

Comment: @James do you have any other suggestions? The array is somehow riding itself...

Comment: Do you have an example of getCurrentStage, or what `index` contains?

Comment: Yeah, honestly man, I knew this was going to be confusing, so I actually made a video.