# Previous array elements are undefined when I add new ones to index

Tags: javascript

This is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660192/how-to-push-value-of-input-on-jquerys-keyup-into-an-array?noredirect=1#comment76312825_44660192) I asked earlier yesterday, where I initially thought it was jQuery's `.bind` or `.keyup` event that was causing it, but it's a lot more mysterious then that.

I created a [video over here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xl1sKLDrA_A) to explain in more detail, sorry for the quality.

```
var stopTimeArray = []
$('.mdl-textfield__input.stage-time.stop_time').bind('input', function() {
    console.log('stopTimeArray', stopTimeArray)
    var stopTimeVal = parseInt(this.value)
    console.log('stopTimeVal', stopTimeVal) //always prints [] on new form
    var index = parseInt($(currentStage()).attr('rel')) - 1
    console.log('index', index)
    stopTimeArray[index] = stopTimeVal
    updateTTH();
    debugger;
  });

  function updateTTH() {
    console.log(stopTimeArray)
    // other code...
  }
```

Basically I have a form that you can duplicate. I just want to get the value of a specific input when it's edited, push it to an array so I can get the total. For example, suppose in the **first form**, I enter `20`, it will print

> stopTimeArray ► []
>
> stopTimeVal 2
>
> index 0
>
> ► [2]

...

> stopTimeArray ► [2]
>
> stopTimeVal 20
>
> index 0
>
> ► [20]

This is perfect, it's just what I want. However, the problem occurs when I want to add something to the **second form**. Suppose we want to add `8` in our new form. This is the result...

> stopTimeArray ► []

I don't know why, but it's clear that somehow the stopTimeArray is being overridden and reset.

> stopTimeVal 8
>
> index 1
>
> ► (2) [undefined × 1, 8]

This is a problem that I am so lost in, because I actually think the machine is wrong (jk). But if you guys know anything about this please let me know :)

EDIT:
currentStage() is working perfectly as expected, but here it is incase you guys want to see it.

```
var currentStage = function findCurrentStageContainer() {
     var numStages = document.getElementsByClassName('stage-container').length;
     for (var i = 0; i <  numStages; i++) {
       if (!hasClass(document.getElementsByClassName('stage-container')[i], "hidden-form")) {
         return document.getElementsByClassName('stage-container')[i]
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Did you try to unfold the array by clicking on the ► button on the left? The unfolded values are the real ones, the `[undefined x 1, 8]` is just a preview of the array when the console log happened.

Comment: How does `currentStage()` work? Where is its code?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, Yeah it's undefined. currentStage() is working perfectly fine.

Comment: How many stages there could be? Why don't you fill the whole array every time an input is changed? And `currentStage` could be optimised a lot (you're calling `getElementsByClassName` three times for god sake).

Comment: Because if I push, then every time I type a 2 digit number, it will put 2 values in.

Comment: No. No, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/9odcyw0t/. Create a new array every time.

Comment: This isn't the best solution, but since I have no idea about the rest of your code, I won't be much of a help. (Bright side: at least you won't be needing the `currentStage` function LOL).